# Android ImageView PinchZoom Multiple Layout

Tags: android, xml, layout, dynamic, zooming

just stuck here, i have no idea how to display in multiple xml file.i have button1.xml, button2.xml and button3.xml.  I want to be able to switch these views dynamically in an activity.

```
> <LinearLayout
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent" >
>       <com.apps.example.TouchImageView
>       android:id="@+id/snoop"
>       android:layout_width="match_parent"
>       android:src="@drawable/keutamaandua"
>       android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

java file

```
public class TouchImageViewActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.button1);
        TouchImageView img = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.snoop);
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.keutamaandua);
        img.setMaxZoom(4f);
```

Answer (score 0):

`setVisibility()` should solve your problem. Use `view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` and `view.setVisibility(View.GONE)` to dynamically show and hide views in your activity layout. Or if you have multiple xml files and you want to show them in same activity then just call `setContentView(id)` with appropriate id again.